# SignalR in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I am having an windows application which is a ticket booking system. In my datagridview(in edit mode) when operator types something(destination) a grid comes up to display available tickets for that destination. Operator picks the ticket and book. This works fine. But when multiple operators are booking tickets, they are seeing different ticket count, and at the time of booking it says ticket sold off because other operator booked that.
So what I am thinking is, if the ticket data will come from signalr and it is updated always with all operators.Is it worth giving a chance?

Comment: Why not use WCF duplex channels, if you have a WinForms application. SignalR is mostly for web applications.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications

Comment: There will always be races - you'll still have to cope with two operators clicking "book" at exactly the same time and only one of them winning. Make sure you *do* deal with that situation, whatever else you may do.

Comment: @Mihail I disagree, SignalR can indeed be used for hosted applications as well. Just because it fills a hole in the web that wasn't previously filled, it doesn't mean that it isn't useful outside.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes that extra check will always be there. I want to confirm that this is a right approach to do. Further my database is mySql, I believe that will not any issue

Comment: Is there any example of fetching data from signalr in datagridview? Any link would be helpful

Comment: It's OK to use [SignalR in a Windows Forms Application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b). Also as another option you can take a look at [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am using mySql so SqlDependency will not work. I am asking a lot but again Windows application with mySql db, signalR? Is there any performance impact

Comment: As mentioned before you can use SignalR with your windows forms clients. Here is also [another example](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/how-to-push-data-from-server-to-client-using-signalr.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the link. So what I am trying to do is, when operator books a ticket, my datagridview source will be updated from signalR, so when new operator is searching for the ticket it has updatded info. I will update on the progress. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, in general in a ticket sale system, *usually* you need locking mechanisms.